# Deployment Error using Force.com IDE in Eclipse

Tags: force.com, ide, eclipse

Hoping I can get some help with an Eclipse deployment error.  I am trying to update a Layout, but I am getting an error saying a button I have on that object is not present.   The error is:

```
layouts/KNDY4__Accounting_Entry__c-KNDY4__Account Entry Layout.layout -- Error: In field: customButtons - no WebLink named KNDY4__Accounting_Entry__c.Account_Inquiry.
```

However, I have confirmed that the Web Link is present in my XML file:

```
<webLinks>
        <fullName>Account_Inquiry</fullName>
        <availability>online</availability>
        <displayType>button</displayType>
        <hasMenubar>false</hasMenubar>
        <hasScrollbars>true</hasScrollbars>
        <hasToolbar>false</hasToolbar>
        <height>600</height>
        <isResizable>true</isResizable>
        <linkType>page</linkType>
        <masterLabel>Account Inquiry</masterLabel>
        <openType>newWindow</openType>
        <page>KNDY4__AccountInquiry</page>
        <position>none</position>
        <protected>false</protected>
        <showsLocation>false</showsLocation>
        <showsStatus>false</showsStatus>
    </webLinks>
```

Any feedback on troubleshooting steps would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Are you only trying to deploy the `KNDY4__Accounting_Entry__c-KNDY4__Account Entry Layout` layout?

Answer (score 1):

The weblink is available in your object (the xml file where you copied the above weblink info from, but you're not having it in your deployment.

As you're deploing the layout, where the button is on you also have to include the button itself.

Your package.xml needs to include:

```
<types>
     <member>KNDY4__Accounting_Entry__c.Account_Inquiry</member>
     <name>WebLink</name>
</types
```